# Postfix/Amavis : send group messages separately and do not fail if one recipient fails

Tags: postfix, smtp, amavis

## Background:

We have a online shop which is using a SMTP server to send messages. When a customer place an order, the system sends the confirmation to the customer's address (A), and a copy to other two accounts (B and C) which are registered in the same SMTP server.

## Problem:

If the customer input a wrong email address (example: `tom@gmail.co` <-- note that it should be `com`), it bounces all of the group and neither (B) or (C) get the message.

Logs:

```
Apr 25 10:12:37 smtp_server postfix/smtpd[8153]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from localhost[127.0.0.1]: 450 4.1.2 <tom@gmail.co>: Recipient address rejected: Domain not found; from=<system@orders.example.com> to=<tom@gmail.co> proto=ESMTP helo=<localhost>
Apr 25 10:12:37 smtp_server amavis[12654]: (12654-06) (!)mail_via_smtp: NOTICE: aborting SMTP session, Bail out, DATA accepted but tempfailed recips, not a LMTP input at (eval 134) line 979.
Apr 25 10:12:37 smtp_server amavis[12654]: (12654-06) (!)FWD from <system@orders.example.com> -> <tom@gmail.co>,<backup@example.com>,BODY=7BIT 451 4.5.0 From MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025) during fwd-data-chkpnt (Bail out, DATA accepted but tempfailed recips, not a LMTP input at (eval 134) line 979.): id=12654-06
Apr 25 10:12:37 smtp_server amavis[12654]: (12654-06) Blocked MTA-BLOCKED {TempFailedOpenRelay}, [111.222.111.222]:41916 [111.222.111.222] <system@orders.example.com> -> <tom@gmail.co>,<backup@example.com>, Queue-ID: 4DA411806E13C, Message-ID: <cf7e32ff-1b33-9672-808a-0edfe7ede5f4@aju-cil.com>, mail_id: DZSKWfuau0Pu, Hits: 0.8, size: 745, 3627 ms
Apr 25 10:12:37 smtp_server postfix/smtp[31968]: 4DA411806E13C: to=<tom@gmail.co>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024, delay=3.8, delays=0.17/0/0/3.6, dsn=4.1.2, status=deferred (host 127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1] said: 450 4.1.2 id=12654-06 - Temporary MTA failure on relaying, from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025): 450 4.1.2 <tom@gmail.co>: Recipient address rejected: Domain not found (in reply to end of DATA command))
```

## Expected:

Both (B) or (C) should receive the email regardless if (A) address is wrong.

## Note:

The same happens if I send an email to those accounts from my personal computer with TO, CC or BCC. So I conclude that something can be done at the mail server.

Is there any setting in postfix or amavis that is preventing that to happen or that i should add in order to make it work?

Comment: Why do you send outgoing mail through antivirus check?

Comment: @MichaelHampton to prevent infected clients to send virus through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exact same issue. I was able to resolve by adding a **warn_if_reject** in front of **reject_unknown_recipient_domain** in my **smtpd_recipient_restrictions**